# Using yeoman for development of a mobile website?

Tags: mobile, workflow, toolchain, yeoman

I am currently looking for a tool/workflow to support me in creating a mobile version of our website. Due to the main subject of our website, this should be a dedicated mobile version instead of a responsive version of our main site.

I came across yeoman and it looks really promising with a lot of features that I would be using like CSS and JS minifying, Spriting etc., a lot of tools that support me for the deployment of the webpage.

However as far as I can see the main focus for yeoman is on "normal" web apps, not for mobile. Am I right? Has someone used yeoman already for a mobile website and what was the experience and/or points to look out for? Are there any other alternatives to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [mobile-boilerpate](https://github.com/sindresorhus/generator-mobile-boilerplate) generator for yeoman.
It scaffolds out [H5BP Mobile](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/) Boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

You are right Yeoman is for any web app you want to build; not just mobile specific.

For a mobile version of a website; they can be made similar to desktop sites although you still have to keep responsiveness in mind as not all devices are the same size.

In terms of a framework to consider, [Lungo](http://lungo.tapquo.com/) is a brilliant UI framework that can be used to make a native looking website.